# Checking the referrer Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

i'm trying to make code check if user click from Facebook it redirect to another page of my website that share on Facebook.
my website is using APP to login and problem is when new user trying to login using my app and redirect to website another page too.but i want it on main website.
**Demo for example** : https://youda.info/fb/

```
<script>
var ref = document.referrer;
if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?facebook\.com(\/|$)/i)){
window.location.replace("https://youda.info/fb/app.php?app_id=1);
} else if (ref.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?youda\.com(\/|$)/i))  {
}
</script>
```

Comment: so, is there something not working with the 5 lines of code you posted?

Comment: everything is working but i just want when new user login  from this https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=491160211054796 ...... not redirect

Comment: and user from this url https://youda.info/fb/pages/594b4c280911c.html 
make it redirect